# TypeScript Decorators and Circular Dependencies

Tags: javascript, typescript, undefined, decorator, circular-dependency

Consider the sample of inter-dependent code (below) that makes use of decorators.

Now consider the following workflow (yes, I do want to pass the actual exported classes since I need to use them later):

1. App imports and runs `Parent.ts`
2. `@Test(Child)` causes the app to import `Child.ts` while decorating
3. Note: the class `Parent` has not yet been reached by the code
4. In `Child.ts`, the `@Test(Parent)` decorator is executed
5. At this point, `Parent` is undefined and cannot be passed to the decorator.

As you see, there's a nasty circular dependency going on and I cannot see a way of being able to apply decorators that take classes as arguments which reference each other.

Please note, I used `@Test` for brevity as an example.  The actual decorators are `@HasMany` and `@BelongsTo` - so I do have an actual use case here.

**My question to you:** "Is there a solution to this issue?"

My fear is that there isn't, unless TypeScript's compiled code is changed so as to defer the decoration process until all involved code has been imported.

#### Code example:

`Decorators.ts`:

```
    export function Test(passedClass: Function): Function {
        return function (model: Function): void {
            console.log(typeof passedClass);
        };
    }
```

`Parent.ts`:

```
    import {Child} from "./Child";
    import {Test} from "./Decorators";

    @Test(Child)
    export class Parent {

    }
```

`Child.ts`:

```
    import {Parent} from "./Parent";
    import {Test} from "./Decorators";

    @Test(Parent)
    export class Child {

    }
```

Comment: It's not recursion as it's a circular dependencies. Why can't each class test itself?

Comment: Thanks - circular reference - that's the term I was grasping for.  I named it `@Test` for brevity.  It's actually `@HasMany` and `@BelongsTo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can postpone actions performed in decorator - you can overcome the limitation and break circular dependency. From the names of your real decorators @HasMany and @BelongsTo it looks like you are attaching some sort of the metadata  to each class for the later usage - if so here is my suggestion:

1. Extend your @Test decorator signature

`export function Test(passedClass: Function | string)`

I assume here that the decorator will store meta information in some sort of static dictionary, like: . Where properties can look like

```
{
    hasMany: {new(): any} | string
    belongsTo: {new(): any} | string
}
```

2. Inside decorator create new properties object with hasMany/belongsTo properties set to `passedClass`. If `passedClass` is not string - check all already added properties and replace any hasMany/belongsTo that are of string type and equal current `passedClass.name`
3. Remove reference to Child from Parent.

This is somewhat naive implementation and you can implement some private fields instead to hide the intermediate string data and keep away from exposing union type fields.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work since the very act of passing the class causes the circular dependency (all actions performed by the decorator are already deferred to the end of my bootstrapping process). Thanks though!

Comment: The idea behind tjis approach is to pass string instead of class to skip introducing circular dependency

Comment: Oh right, my apologies, Amid. I guess I'm just struggling to find a way to get the actual, e.g., `User` class from `"User"`.  I'll give it another go.

Comment: Usually this is not an issue as all of your 'entities' are inevitably be marked with decorators that adds corresponding metadata. If you introduce lets say 'Entity' decorator - that will fill in the static map of string class names to their constructor functions. After that you will at any time be able to construct entity (User in your case) by having its string name only.

Comment: Okay, my apologies. I totally misunderstood the approach. I've now implemented it and it works perfectly by just searching my metadata-store by class name and then setting-up the entity associations.

Answer (score 6):

Hit the same problem today. I solved it slightly differently, by replacing `@Test(Parent)` by `@Test(() => Parent)`.

Instead of tracking the class constructor (`Parent`) in metadata, I track the thunk that returns the constructor (`() => Parent`). This delays the evaluation of the `Parent` imported variable until the thunk is invoked, which does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

How about doing the same, but structuring your code differently?
If both `Child` and `Parent` reside in the same file then it shouldn't be a problem.

That might not sound optimal as it's comfortable to separate  code to modules due to length and logic, but that can be solved in a way.
You can have a main file that has base classes for those, even abstract:

```
// Base.ts
import {Test} from "./Decorators";

@Test(BaseChild)
export abstract class BaseParent {}

@Test(BaseParent)
export abstract class BaseChild {}
```

And then in your specific modules:

```
// Parent.ts
import {BaseParent} from "./Base";

export class Parent extends BaseParent {}
```

And

```
// Child.ts
import {BaseChild} from "./Base";

export class Child extends BaseChild {}
```

Comment: I like the way how moving the decorators to a parent class can solve the issue around the circular dependency (+1).  I did, in the end, go for the other solution that was posted as it allows me to keep all metadata decoration within the main entity/model files, though. Thanks!